# Scrolling when keyboard opened Multiple edittext in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

ok guys

i'm developing an android app which requires lots of edittext fields(so i put them into recyclerview for better ui performance)

firstly i encountered the input values on edittext fields are not saved so scrolling caused the lose of values in edittext field

i solved the problem by adding textwatcher to edittext fields and saving input data but now im encountering another problem:
just try the following steps in proper order:

```
1- tap to some edittext input field(soft keyboard open ups simultaneously)
2- now scroll the recyclerview to other edittext fields (so edittext which you entering value into it, disappears from screen)
3- and try to input some words into it by keyboard
```

after these steps
edittext which you edited doesnt contain any value.

instead, other randomly choosen edittext gains the value which you entered

probably recyclerview's reusing mechanism is causing it, not sure

i dont want to disable scrolling when soft keyboard opened to fix this possible behaviour/issue so is there another way to solve this problem?

EDIT:

```
public class SampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{
private static List<String> mEditTextValues = new ArrayList<>();

public SampleAdapter(List<String> dataSet){
     mEditTextValues = dataSet;
}
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new CustomViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.edittext,parent,false));
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CustomViewHolder viewHolder = ((CustomViewHolder)holder);
    viewHolder.mEditText.setTag(position);
    viewHolder.mEditText.setText(mEditTextValues.get(position));
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mEditTextValues.size();
}

public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private EditText mEditText;
    public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mEditText = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                if(mEditText.getTag()!=null){
                    mEditTextValues.set((int)mEditText.getTag(),editable.toString());
                }
            }
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Code snippet would help

Comment: Ok, i added the adapter class

Comment: i pass initial edittext values by passing list to constructor of adapter as parameter

Comment: and i implemented textwatcher to save the edittext input values

Comment: Did you notify the adapter that your data set has changed?

Comment: do i need to do it on first run?

Comment: i mean first load (while creating adapter constructor)

Comment: After mEditTextValues.set() notify adapter by calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: For now you are updating the values on your list but Adapter has no idea about it.

Comment: ahhh i got it, i know now, thanx man you saved my day

Comment: so just i need to call notifiyDataSetChanged after mEditTextValues.set() right?

Comment: Yes. That is the concept, either notify adapter or RecyclerView, your call.

Comment: but also what if i still typing via soft keyboard after scrolling into another edittext? (and edittext which im typing into it disappears from screen)

Comment: That already depends on your logic, if there are too many then you should consider wrapping it in a ScrollView instead of RecyclerView. I have no idea about your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop editing random place, you can hide the soft keypad when the current editing edit text starts non-focusing.

Adapter.bindView

```
viewHolder.mEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if (b == false) {
                    hideKeyboard(view.getContext(), view);
                }
            }
        });
```

To hide the keypad

```
/**
 * To hide a keypad.
 *
 * @param context
 * @param view
 */
public static void hideKeyboard(Context context, View view) {
    if ((context == null) || (view == null)) {
        return;
    }
    InputMethodManager mgr =
            (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: also can i put that listener into createviewholder instead of bindView ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a ScrollView in your layout but there is no code posted

Comment: i tried to use scrollview but i have more than 80 edittext so ui was hell on scrollview, then i used recyclerview

Comment: Could you post some code, 80 edittexts seems like it would be hell on any view

Comment: Ok, i added my adapter class

Comment: yeah view number is high but RecyclerView fixed the entire lag and performance issues dramatically, it scrolls very smootly

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your TextWatcher in onBindViewHolder it will work

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    CustomViewHolder viewHolder = ((CustomViewHolder)holder);

    viewHolder.mEditText.setText(mEditTextValues.get(position));

viewHolder.mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
               mEditTextValues.set(position,mEditText.getText().toString())
}
        });
}
```